# How to display toast when contact was added?

Tags: android, android-contacts, toast

I think everyone knows of adding contacts in android devices. When contact was added in device after successful adding of contact we get a toast message as **"Contact Saved"**. 
But what i want is to get my own toast message like **"(contacts name) Contact Saved"**  (like codefinder Contact Saved) rather than getting default toast message. How can i get that one....

Answer (score 4):

You can not overwrite the "default" toast that you get in the contacts app. That is app specific. You can however register a broadcast receiver to listen to contact events.

A receiver could be registered like:

```
    <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />

            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="com.android.contact" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have some idea about what you have posted, Thanks for your answer. But what i am looking is, is there any possibility of changing default things declared in android.... anyways thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) class like this

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "YOUR CUSTOM TEXT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to create your own toast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am not asking regarding how to display toast messages. I am asking regarding how to overwrite the default toast messages displayed in android devices...

Comment: Ok, sorry about misunderstanding.